# Duration problem in a set of TranslateAnimation in Android

Tags: android, animation, duration

I have to animate an image as per (x,y) from one point to another point, then that point to another point and so on. I have around 300 points. For that I am using the following code.

```
/** code starts **/

public class CircleAnimation extends Activity implements OnPreparedListener {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

 ImageView imv1;
 int totalAnimTime = 0;
 double[][] points =  {{258.8505,143.2875,67},
        {259.642, 143.3665,120},
        {260.429, 142.992,240},
             {259.257, 139.3575,180},
        ......................
                   ......................
        {255.1335,146.8135,67},
        {255.1395,146.794,67},
        {255.0635,146.7785,67},
        {254.9045,146.797,1200}
         };
 int j=0;

 double loc[] = new double[2];
 double x1 = 0,y1 = 0,x2 = 0,y2 = 0,anim_end=0, xstart=258.8505, ystart=143.2875, xnow, ynow;
 protected boolean _active = true;
    protected int _animTime = 66;  
    int k=1;

    double xFactor = 1.779167, yFactor = 1.5;
    private int displayWidth, displayHeight;


 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        

        imv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imv1);

        try{
            LaunchInAnimation();
        }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    class LocalAnimationListener implements AnimationListener {

  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation){
   imv1.post(mLaunchSecondAnimation);    
   k = k ++;
  }
  public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
  {
  }

  public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
  {
  }
 };

 private Runnable mLaunchSecondAnimation = new Runnable(){

  public void run(){
   LaunchInAnimation();
  }
 };

 LocalAnimationListener MyAnimationListener = new LocalAnimationListener();


 public void LaunchInAnimation() {


  //animation
  if(k<points.length) {
   if(k==0) {
    x1 = xstart;
          y1 = ystart;
          anim_end=1;
   } else {
       x1 = points[k-1][0];
          y1 = points[k-1][1];
   }
      x2 = points[k][0];
      y2 = points[k][1];
      _animTime = (int) (points[k][2]);

      TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation((float)x1, (float)x2, (float)y1, (float)y2);
      translateAnimation.setDuration(_animTime); 
      translateAnimation.setFillBefore(true);
      translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
      translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(MyAnimationListener);
      imv1.startAnimation(translateAnimation);

      totalAnimTime +=  _animTime;
  }
 }
}

/** code ends **/
```

To complete all the animations it should take *totalAnimTime*, but it is taking less time to complete. Moreover this time is varying from one device to another device. For this, I facing problem to synchronize other event. What is the problem in this code? Is there any other better way to control this type animation.

Answer (score 0):

I was messing with this variance in performance myself, and then I switched to OpenGL to do all my rendering and have since found everything much smoother and simpler once you understand what you're doing.

- If you feel OpenGL/SurfaceView is a little too dense for what you're asking for, try using Canvas?

Should be much easier with one of those because they're more stable from device to device. XML animations are simply tricking you into thinking they're animations, their actual X/Y don't ever really change. They have to "flicker" from their original X/Y to the "next step X/Y" right before drawn if I'm correct....